# Redirection for localization does not work

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect, localization, docusaurus

I have a website by Facebook docusaurus and docker. Here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  docusaurus:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    environment:
      CERTBOT_EMAIL: softtimur@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
      - ./build:/app
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

volumes:
  letsencrypt:
```

Here is `conf.d/server-block.conf`.

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/jpeg image/png image/svg+xml image/x-icon;


server {
  listen  3002;
  absolute_redirect off;
  root  /app;

  location = / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /docs {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /addinHelp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /privacy {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/privacy.html redirect;
  }

  location = /docs/helpdeskAndContact {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/helpdesk-contact redirect;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}


upstream backend {
   server 178.62.87.72:443;
}


server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.tech/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.tech/privkey.pem;
    server_name www.example.tech;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "";

    proxy_ssl_name "www.backend.io";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
   
    location ~ /auth/(.*) {                                                                                            
          proxy_pass  https://backend/example/auth/$1?$query_string;
          proxy_set_header Host www.example.tech;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          http://docusaurus:3002/;

        # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove socketio error
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that all my webpages in Chinese start with `www.example.tech/zh-CN/`, e.g., `www.example.tech/zh-CN/docs/introduction`. I would like to make the `zh-CN` case insensitive such that `www.example.tech/zh-cn/...` or `www.example.tech/ZH-cn/...` work as well.

ChatGPT suggested me to add the following redirection to the 443 server block:

```
    location ~* ^/zh-(cn|CN)(/.*)?$ {
        rewrite ^/zh-(cn|CN)(/.*)?$ /zh-CN$2 last;
    }
```

I tried it, but browsers said that there were many redirects. It just did not work.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried it, but browsers said that there were many redirects.

Probably because the `rewrite` is firing even after the URL has been rewritten to the desired format, causing Nginx to continually try to redirect the already-correct URL.

For a comprehensive solution, you could go with a general catch for any case combination of "`zh`" followed by any case combination of "`cn`", and make sure it does *not* match the already correct format.

```
location ~* ^/[Zz][Hh]-(?!CN)[Cc][Nn](/.*)?$ {
    rewrite ^/[Zz][Hh]-[Cc][Nn](/.*)?$ /zh-CN$1 last;
}
```

With:

- `^/[Zz][Hh]-(?!CN)[Cc][Nn](/.*)?$`: matches any variation of `/zh-CN` in different cases, but due to the [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!CN)`, it does not match the exact `/zh-CN`.
- The `[Zz][Hh]-[Cc][Nn]` would capture all variations of `/zh-CN` in different cases, and rewrites them to the correct format.

Comment: Thank you @VonC, I have been sick since one week, will test your solution once I'm covered.

Comment: @SoftTimur No problem. I hope you get well soon.